# airconsole simulator isn't showing my updated code when refreshed

Tags: airconsole

I'm trying to test my game on the site using the simulator page. however I'm running into a problem. no mater what it seems like my page updates are not changing on the simulator. I've tested locally on the pages, and they work fine.

anyone know? i haven't seen anything in documentation

Answer (score 0):

At least for me when I'm testing the controllers for the Unity project, or another HTML / Javascript project I need to clear the cache once in a while to make it work.

For Firefox; Options (top right corner) - Privacy & Security (left menu) - Clear data (button on the right)
(I untick the "Cookies and Site Data" because it does not affect to this problem.)

And just to make it clear, it's not an AirConsole problem. If you have ever tried to create a local website and you are testing stuff this might happen as well. Also, you don't have to do this everytime something changes.

Comment: Ive done the hard cache reset and everything, still didn't refresh the game, maybe somethign else is up on my system right now im not thinking of.. i have been overworking a lot. so probably pebkac of doing it tired.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that if you add something a question mark after the address and put something random after it, it will refresh well again (a bit like what is done in web with images to avoid caching sometimes).

**Example:**

Original url: http://www.airconsole.com/#http://192.168.1.2/game

Url after 1st change: http://www.airconsole.com/#http://192.168.1.2/game?1

Url after 2nd change: Url after change: http://www.airconsole.com/#http://192.168.1.2/game?2

etc...

**UPDATE**

I've also found that the following works:

- Original url: `http://www.airconsole.com/#http://192.168.1.2/game`
- Open a tab with `http://192.168.1.2/game/screen.html`
- Do CMD + Shift + R on OSX or Ctrl + F5 on Windows when using Chrome
- Switch to the original airconsole URL tab and do the previous step
- Your game is now refreshed